# Rails 3.2.16 dup() not working as spected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need some help from you tonight. I'm developing a personal project where I need to duplicate a record and set new values since it's not a full duplication. Here is my code:

```
def create
  viejo = current_user.prestamos.find(params[:prestamo_id])
  @prestamo = viejo.dup
  if @prestamo.save
    viejo.reajustado = true
    viejo.save
    @prestamo.total_pagado = 0
    @prestamo.monto = ((viejo.monto*1.2) - viejo.total_pagado)
    @prestamo.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

The total_pagado = 0 and the monto = (calculation) part is not working. I really don't know what's wrong.

My console shows this:

(40.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "prestamos" SET "reajustado" = 't', "updated_at" = '2014-02-15 21:30:14.836035' WHERE "prestamos"."id" = 611
   (6.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

Thank you in advance

Comment: First suspicion: you've violated a constraint in your database, as you're facing a 'rollback'. Maybe a unique constraint? If not, I would debug this code, and see whether @prestamo is valid, using is_valid? and check if any errors are present on this model

Comment: well, actually the calculation was returning a float value, so I user .to_i and everything worked.